# OSGI vs Apache Felix

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, modularity

I have to create a project for school. We want to create a system that monitors sensors. Since sensors develop very much, there is the possibility that they use other sensors in a couple of years. To capture that problem, we want to create a system that lets users write plugins to monitor the sensors.

I am looking at different frameworks, mainly OSGI.

Could someone tell me the difference between Apache Felix and OSGI? Also, is OSGI still active?

Thanks!

Comment: `OSGI` is the API specification. `Apache Felix` is the implementation of OSGI. Other implementations include `Karaf`, `Eclipse equinox`, `Prosyst`. If you want to develop applications monitoring sensors, then you should take a look at `Intel XDK IOT Edition` with nodejs.

Comment: @11thdimension Karaf is not an OSGi Framework implementation.

Comment: You're right, it's a bundle using Felix/Equinox. It's not an implementation of OSGI.

Comment: OSGi is evil.  I've worked on serveral large projects using OSGi, and will absolutely never (knowingly) take another job on an OSGi project.

Comment: Why is it evil?

Comment: Because it forces you to write strong modular software and no option of cheating. This is very hard for a lot of people used to everything-can and dependencies are good, more dependencies is better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OSGi is a set of specifications, which are developed and released by an industry consortium called the [OSGi Alliance](https://www.osgi.org/).

[Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/) is a project in which several of the OSGi specifications are implemented. So whereas OSGi gives you a specification (essentially a PDF document!), Apache Felix is actual software that you can run. Because Felix conforms to the OSGi specification, any code that you write to run on Felix will also run on any of the other OSGi implementations. These include Eclipse Equinox, Knopflerfish and Concierge.

Yes OSGi is **very** active, and is particularly relevant to your requirements. Large companies (e.g. Bosch, Deutche Telekom, Huawei) are using it to build IoT systems and shipping them to people's homes, vehicles etc right now.

You might also look at [Eclipse Kura](http://www.eclipse.org/kura/), which builds IoT functionality e.g. device communications on top of OSGi.